# How to convert a 'by' [list] output into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, reshape2, combn

data= data.frame(col1=c('m1','m1','m1','m2','m2', 'm2','m3', 'm3'), class=c('a','b','c','a','b','c', 'a', 'b'))I have a data.frame with 2 columns, the 1st column is a list of models, the 2nd column a list of model attributes. I need to show combination of models based on the attributes they share. I  got the list of combination using the 'by' function as follows:

```
data= data.frame(col1=c('m1','m1','m1','m2','m2','m3'), class=c('a','b','c','a','b','c'))

data.ls=by(data$col1, data$class,function(x) t(combn(x, 2)))
```

The output is exactly what I need, but I need it in a data.frame format instead of a list and the name of the 'class' that appears at the top of each list should be listed in a third column:

```
# data$class: a
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,] m1   m2
# [2,] m1   m3
# [3,] m2   m3
# Levels: m1 m2 m3
```

So, I tried this:

```
as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",data.ls))
```

But the output shows only the combination of 'col1' (using the id values instead of the name) and not the 'class' attribute, which was at the top of each list in the 'by' output. The output of do.call looks like this:

```
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  2
# 2  1  2
# 3  1  3
```

Also tried this:

```
do.call("rbind.data.frame",data.ls)
```

And got this error: Error in NextMethod() : invalid value

The final table should look like this:

```
data.final= data.frame(col1=c('m1','m1','m1'), col2=c('m2', 'm2', 'm3'), class=c('a','b','c'))
```

@Richard Scrivens proposed the following:

```
newDF <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(data.ls, as.character)), names(data.ls), row.names = NULL)
```

The output is:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 names.data.ls.
1 m1 m1 m2 m2 m3 m3              a
2 m1 m1 m2 m2 m3 m3              b
3 m1 m2 m1 m2 m1 m2              c
```

The output in this format is, to me, less clear, in term of the combinations, than the 'by' list.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: as.data.frame isn't of use?

Comment: Perhaps, you could use `aggregate` to begin with `aggregate(col1 ~ class, data, function(x) t(combn(x, 2)))`?

Comment: @RichardScriven tapply example---- tab <- do.call(rbind, with(data, {
  tapply(as.character(col1), class, function(x) c(combn(x, 2)))
}))
   ---- works great. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid this by using `tapply`, instead of `by`.  Actually, `tapply` is the workhorse function for `by`.  The following result just needs a `cbind` and `as.data.frame`, but you can see the point.

```
do.call(rbind, with(data, {
    tapply(as.character(col1), class, function(x) c(combn(x, 2)))
}))
#   [,1] [,2]
# a "m1" "m2"
# b "m1" "m2"
# c "m1" "m3"
```

For the same result, your `by` call can be changed a little.

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(by(data$col1, data$class, combn, 2), as.character))
#   [,1] [,2]
# a "m1" "m2"
# b "m1" "m2"
# c "m1" "m3"
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard Scriven. Your solution works, in principle, with this example. But when I get more than 1 combination for a single class then I'm not sure how to read the output. I'll  made a little change to the original example to make this point.

Comment: @LuluPor  - try my edit, with the `tapply` solution.

Answer (score 0):

'aggregate' output seems what you want:

```
aggregate(col1~class,data,function(x) t(combn(x, 2)))
  class col1.1 col1.2
1     a     m1     m2
2     b     m1     m2
3     c     m1     m3
```